# Angularjs get number of fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to ask how many choices you want? if user enters 10 then 10 choices should be displayed. I tried hard but this is giving memory error.

dynamicform.jsp

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="dynamicFieldsPlugin">
<head>
 <!--  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.2" data-semver="3.3.2" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

-->

## Dynamic Form Fields Creation Plugin

```
  <label for="choice" ng-show="showChoiceLabel(choice)">Choices</label>

    <label>How many Choices you want?</label>
    <input type="text" ng-modal="{{nochoices}}" name="" value="{{nochoices}}">
    <button ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" ng-click="addNewChoiceno(nochoices)">Add Choice</button>

  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <br/><br/>
    <!-- <button ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add Choice</button> -->

    <button ng-click="removeNewChoice()">Remove Choice</button>

    <input type="text" ng-modal="{{choice.name}}" name="" placeholder="Enter a restaurant name" value="{{choice.id}}">
  </div>
</div>
<!--jQuery Scripts -->
<script src="js/angularjs/1.4.8/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
  var app = angular.module("dynamicFieldsPlugin", []);

  app.controller("dynamicFields", function($scope) {


 $scope.nochoices = 10;
 $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1', name: 'choice1'}];



 $scope.addNewChoice = function() {

 var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;

 $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, 'name' : 'choice' + newItemNo});
```

};

```
  $scope.addNewChoiceno = function(nochoices) {


     for(var i=$scope.choices.length;i<nochoices+$scope.choices.length;i++){
     $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + i, 'name' : 'choice' + i});
     }
     $scope.choices.length=$scope.choices.length+nochoices;
   };

  $scope.removeNewChoice = function() {

 var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length-1;

 if ( newItemNo !== 0 ) {

  $scope.choices.pop();

 }

 };



 $scope.showAddChoice = function(choice) {

 return choice.id === $scope.choices[$scope.choices.length-1].id;
```

};

```
});
```

error

out of memory

Comment: please Share a fiddle or plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it looks like the for loop will continue while `i` is less than  `$scope.choices.length + nochoices`

```
for(var i=$scope.choices.length;i<nochoices+$scope.choices.length;i++){
     $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + i, 'name' : 'choice' + i});
}
```

Unfortunately you are pushing onto `$scope.choices` *within* the loop. This means if `i` grows by 1, so does `$scope.choices.length` meaning the loop condition will always be true, and the loop will continue forever.

Perhaps change the above code to this:

```
for(var i=$scope.choices.length;i<nochoices;i++){
     $scope.choices.push({'id' : 'choice' + i, 'name' : 'choice' + i});
}
```

Comment: Error: choice is undefined
$scope.showAddChoice@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.4.8/app.js:53:6
$parseFunctionCall@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:12404:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:14300:34
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:14571:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js:1455:9
invoke@http://localhost:8083/example1/js/angularjs/1.3.15/...

Comment: Hm - unsure. But l bet you put this in a Plunkr or jsfiddle, someone would solve this in minutes. And its very likely you would solve it in the process :)